# How to find bounds of solution to fixed point problem

Tags: systems-of-equations, fixed-point-theorems, implicit-function

I have a two-equation system of implicit functions,
\begin{align}
0 & = f(x,y) = a y^\alpha \left(\bar{x} - x\right)^\gamma - x \\
0 & = g(x,y) = a x^\beta \left(\bar{y} - y\right)^\gamma - y
\end{align}
with $x \in \left[0,\bar{x}\right]$, $y \in \left[0,\bar{y}\right]$, $a>0$, and $\alpha,\beta, \gamma > 0$. The parameters $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$, $a$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ all are fixed beforehand. The equations satisfy the contraction property (because $f(0,y) > 0$, $f(\bar{x},y) < 0$, and $f_x<0$ and $g(x,0)>0$, $g(x,\bar{y})<0$, and $g_y<0$), so I know that unique solutions for the endogenous variables, $x$ and $y$, exist.

I am trying to derive some properties of $x$ and $y$. Is there a way to determine an upper bound of $x+y$ as a function of the parameters $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$, $a$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$?

Comment: You might want to add more context to your question, so it is a bit more clear. For example, I do not know what $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$, are these fixed quantities beforehand. It is also unclear why you label this under fixed-point-theorems, if this is related to some fixed point problem you might want to give more background.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @StevenCreech, thanks for the suggestions. Please let me know if my attempt at clarifying helped.